# How to Prevent Keyboard Navigation in Editable ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a WPF ComboBox that has a list of numbers. It also has a Custom Item which turns into an Editable Textbox for the user to input their own value.

While in the Editable ComboBox, if I press a number that is in the List of Items, it jumps to that number and out of the Editable TextBox.

**Example:** The ComboBox has Items "1", "2", "3", "Custom".
I click Custom to enter my own value. I press 3 to type "30" and it jumps to Item 3.

**XAML**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,156,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="53" Foreground="White">
    <System:String>1</System:String>
    <System:String>2</System:String>
    <System:String>3</System:String>
    <System:String>Custom</System:String>
</ComboBox>
```

**I make the ComboBox turn from Static to Editable using C#**

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Custom ComboBox Editable
    if ((string)comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Custom" | comboBox1.SelectedValue == null)
    {
        comboBox1.IsEditable = true;
    }

    // Other Items Disable Editable
    if ((string)comboBox1.SelectedItem != "Custom" && comboBox1.SelectedValue != null)
    {
        comboBox1.IsEditable = false;
    }

    // Maintain Editable ComboBox while typing
    if (comboBox1.IsEditable == true)
    {
        comboBox1.IsEditable = true;

        // Clear Custom Text
        comboBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try disabling the `IsTextSearchEnabled` .

Refer to : [IsTextSearchEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.istextsearchenabled(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I used IsTextSearchEnabled="False" in the XAML and it seems to work but there is one side effect. When the ComboBox becomes Editable it retains the word "Custom" in the box instead of clearing it blank like before. I've tried to clear it with comboBox1.Text = string.Empty; and comboBox1.SelectedItem = string.Empty; but it doesn't clear.

Comment: Action action = () =>
                  {
                    // Clear Custom Text
                    comboBox1.Text = string.Empty;
                  };
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, action);

Clear your text like this

Comment: I was able to use comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1; instead of string.Empty and it cleared the Editable Text.